# Python: mysql.connector Failed getting Packet Number

Tags: python, mysql-python

After migrating my code from Windows to MacOs High Sierra, this code

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='db',
                              port=8888)
```

hangs indefinitely and doesn't return any error, I tried to enter wrong credentials just to check if it is really trying to connect to MySQL but still hangs. When I enter wrong host/port it does return an error, this code also is inside of `try and catch`, but it is not proceeding to catch. So I assume that it just hangs on `mysql.connector.connect`.

I appreciate any help, I'm new to Python and MacOS.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**
After waiting a few minutes it is finally show an error: `Failed getting Packet Number.`

Comment: Have you started the local server on port 8888?

Comment: @DYZ yes sir my php code uses the same server and db and it's doing fine.

Comment: @DYZ Sir please see update above. Thank you

Comment: Looks like it's a known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding value on 'unix_socket' parameter:

```
unix_socket='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```